# Explain the code function in call by object

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to y equal to x what is call by object but no function call how it is work how to y value is change

```
y = [1, 2, 3]
x = y
x[:] = [-1]*3
print y
[-1, -1, -1]
```

please explain what will happen in x and y and what is call by object

Comment: There are no function calls here.

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = [1, 2, 3]
x = y
```

`x` and `y` both point to the same list.

```
x[:] = [-1]*3
```

That list is modified, by way of assignment to a whole-object-slice (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)).

```
print y
# [-1, -1, -1]
```

The modified list is printed to the console.

And by the way: there is no "call by object". This is just assignment to a slice (which, as noted in the link, modifies the object).

Answer (score 2):

By doing `x=y` you simply created two references to the same object and as the object is mutable so you can modify it too.

```
>>> y = [1, 2, 3] 
>>> sys.getrefcount(y)
2
>>> x = y          # now y also points to the same object
>>> sys.getrefcount(y) 
3
>>> x is y
True
```

Now `x` and `y` point to the same object in memory:

```
X-----------------------|
                        | 
                  --------------
                  | [1, 2, 3]  |
                  |            |
                  |------------|
                        | 
                        | 
Y-----------------------|
```

Now modify that object using any of the references:

```
>>> x.append(4)    #modify object using either x or y
>>> x,y            
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now remove one of references to that object, say y:

```
>>> del y
>>> x        #but you can still access that object using x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable input....

Answer (score 0):

the list is an object in python ,it is not a simple variable.Just like a pointer in c++
`x=y`just let the pointer equal.The modification on x will also implement on y because they contain the same object.